# Background color not covering the whole div

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this `scss` class:

```
.dropdown-list {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-grey-light-2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;

  li {
    padding: 1rem;
    &:not(:last-child) {
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-grey-light-2);
    }

    &:hover {
      background-color: var(--color-grey-light-2);
    }
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: currentColor;
  }
}
```

However, the background color is not covering the entire `div`:

[image]

As you can see, there is a little border on the top and on the left of my `div`.

For completeness, i'm adding the `html`:

```
<ul class="dropdown-list" style="margin-top: 0.6rem; cursor: pointer">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Add Ingrediets to Shopping List</a>
    </li>
[...]
```

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110

Comment: Please show us [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The "dropdown-list" class is linked on the "ul" tag and not on the "div" tag. You must add some css for the "div" tag or move the class "dropdown-list" depending on your need.
If it is not fixing your issue you should share the part with the "div" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Give a background color in inline css

```html
<div style="background-color: red;"></div>
```

this would work